# Long lines display in powershell with R (and vscode)

Tags: r, powershell, visual-studio-code

Coming from Linux, I had to move to Windows to use the same development environment than the one used in my company.

Having installed R and VsCode (which runs R using PowerShell), it seems that I cannot have lines larger than 75 characters. Characters at the start of the line are cropped and replaced by a $ sign) which is really annoying.

Does someone has a way to solve this (maybe somewhere in the R parameters).

Many thanks.